# Snapshot of UIView gets blurry. Need solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiview

I need to capture a view and then I have to crop some portion of that view.

I am using `captureView` to capture and `cropView` to crop portion. This is my original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu37e.jpg) and This is my output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr1ig.jpg). I want clear Image. I tried to make scale as 0.0f but it didn't work. Any suggestion acceptatble.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect rect = [view bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,NO,2.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return capturedImage;

}
- (UIImage *) cropView:(UIImage *)originalImage frame:(CGRect)frame{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], frame);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: it seems to me it's a resize issue: the original image is 640x960 but the output image is 600x856. Resizing will result in blur...

Comment: I thought about it but was not confirm. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

How did you check the resulting image? Did you save it as a JPG with quality loss? Try using PNG representatiion for lossless results

Also, change the scale constant 2.0f to `[[UIScreen mainscreen] scale]` to be device independent.

Comment: I don't save it. I just capture, crop and share. I have checked through facebook sharing. Let me try [[UIScreen mainscreen] scale]

Comment: Facebook has terrible compression, in my experience.. Can you show the code where you prepare the NSData towards facebook?

Comment: I am using Addthis ! Tried with twitter. Same problem :(